# how to get Contact Name for a given Phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

This my Code I want get Contact Name for a given Contact number But Application forcibly closed . and I got Logcat Error below is Logcat I dont know where am making mistake. please help me how to get contact name for given Conact number.

```
package com.example.example2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NextActvity extends Activity {
    String name;
    Context context = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getContactNameFromNumber("9013714449"), 1000).show();

    }

    private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(number));

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        return name;
        // proceed as you need

    }

}
```

**My logcat**

```
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.example2/com.example.example2.NextActvity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.example.example2.NextActvity.getContactNameFromNumber(NextActvity.java:35)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.example.example2.NextActvity.onCreate(NextActvity.java:20)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
04-25 10:38:09.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: have you added permission in your manifest for read contacts

Comment: yes  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your context variable before using, like this

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because your context is null. Instead of context, you could use your activity like `NextActivity.this`